# Stop backspace form erasing certain output

Tags: c, windows, algorithm, input, char

I am using *getch()* to read input from the keyboard. But if the user enters a wrong number by mistake, they would naturally want to correct it. Pressing the backspace then makes *ch* equal to 0 again, and clears the wrongly entered number from the output (so you cannot see it anymore). I used the ASCII 8 character for a backspace as *getch()* works with ASCII numbers. The backspace now works, but it can now erase the entire output line, including 'Enter an integer:'. How can I go about making the 'Enter an integer:' part unerasable without putting the user's input on a newline? For example:

```
int main(void)
{
    int ch = 0;

    here: printf("Enter an integer:\t");
    ch = getch();
    if(ch == 8) // 8 is ASCII for a backspace
    {
         ch = 0;
         printf("\b \b");
         goto here;
    } 

    // some output

    return 0;
}
```

I don't want "Enter an integer:' and the numbers inputted by the user to be on 2 different lines in the output.

Comment: You basically want the WinAPI equivalent of `curses`. Windows offers [Consoles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @jxh That doesn't really help.

Comment: @ThE411 I pretty much expanded on user3121023's comment in my answer. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: I see, you are trying to manage cursor movement manually. Just don't move the cursor backwards if there wasn't any eraseable input provided.

Comment: `stdin` is often _line buffered_.  Input functions like `getch()` do not receive any input until a line of input was entered.

Comment: `goto` has its use-cases, but your code is none of them! Use a loop statement!

Comment: I agree that a loop would be more optimal here. Nevertheless OP, if you found the answer helpful please make sure to mark it as accepted Good luck coding!

Answer (score 0):

Keep a count variable to tell whether or not you should delete. For example, start the count at 0, and increment it everytime you type an actual character, and decrement it everytime you successfully delete a character. When count is 0, then you shouldn't be allowed to delete and nothing happens to the count variable. It should like this,

```
int main(void)
{
    int ch = 0;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Enter an integer:\t");
    here: ch = getch();
    if(ch == 8) // 8 is ASCII for a backspace
    {
        if(count > 0)
        {
            ch = 0;
            count--;
            printf("\b \b");
        }
        goto here;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c",ch);
        count++;
        goto here;
    }
    //perhaps add an else-if statement here so that
    //when the enter key is pressed, you don't execute 'goto here'

// some output

return 0;
}
```

Also, I changed the location of `here` to `ch = getch();` because you don't want each backspace to reprint "Enter an integer:"